# Get content of tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a text area with the id of 'article'.

Here is what is in my js:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        plugins : "fullpage",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage"
    });
```

And to get the contents of the editor:

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('article').getContent();
    alert(content);
```

But it doesn't appear to work, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow this [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/t0caab) it may help you in figuring out....

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas",
    plugins : "fullpage",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage"
});
```

Function for getting content

```
function get_content() {
var content = tinyMCE.get('article').getContent();
alert(content);
}


<textarea name="article">
  //content here
</textarea>
```

Get the content of editor on button click ...

```
<button onclick="get_content()">Get content</button>
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/t0caab)

Comment: Please post your solution here.

Comment: `tinyMCE.get('article').getContent()` no longer works, but user4389995's answer of using `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` does.

Answer (score 5):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way I can get the content of multiple editors on the same page from one function? Using JS to click each editor and then fetch the active editor seems silly.